# nginx-ingress controller for Azure Kubernetes Service 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm having trouble getting an nginx-ingress controller to work on an Azure Kubernetes Service; it's currently returning 502 Bad Gateway each time I try to hit some Web APIs exposed as Services.
Because I must use an existing certificate, I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls to set up the controller and have followed https://www.markbrilman.nl/2011/08/howto-convert-a-pfx-to-a-seperate-key-crt-file/ to generate a cert and key from a PFX (how the certificate was exported from an Azure Key Vault). I created the secret "aks-ingress-tls" using the certificate including the intermediate and root ceritficates and the decrypted key file.
I have a YAML file to create a deployment, a service to expose it, and an ingress to route to it. Applying this YAML I can access the services via their IP addresses in HTTP, but using HTTPS to the Ingress Controller's EXTERNAL_IP always gives the 502 error.
My YAML File (redacted):

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-api
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-api
        image: [REDACTED]/my-api:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets: 
      - name: data-creds
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    app: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-api
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts: 
    - [REDACTED].co.uk
    secretName: aks-ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: [REDACTED].co.uk
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 443
```

I added a record to my hosts file (I'm on Windows so can't use curl's --resolve) to map [REDACTED].co.uk to the ingress controller's EXTERNAL_IP so I can try accessing it. That's when I get the errors.
A `curl -v https://[REDACTED].co.uk` gives this:

```
VERBOSE: GET https://[REDACTED].co.uk/ with 0-byte payload
curl : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl -v https://[REDACTED].co.uk
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Looking at logs for one of the ingress controller's pods:

```
10.244.1.1 - [10.244.1.1] - - [25/Apr/2019:13:39:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36" 10 0.001 [default-sub360-auth-service-443] 10.244.1.254:443, 10.244.1.3:443, 10.244.1.4:443 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.000, 0.000 502, 502, 502 e44e21c8a2f61f5137c9afdfc64c6584
2019/04/25 13:39:20 [error] 1622#1622: *1127096 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.244.1.1, server: [REDACTED].co.uk, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://10.244.1.254:443/favicon.ico", host: "[REDACTED].co.uk", referrer: "https://[REDACTED].co.uk/"
2019/04/25 13:39:20 [error] 1622#1622: *1127096 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.244.1.1, server: [REDACTED].co.uk, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://10.244.1.3:443/favicon.ico", host: "[REDACTED].co.uk", referrer: "https://[REDACTED].co.uk/"
2019/04/25 13:39:20 [error] 1622#1622: *1127096 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.244.1.1, server: [REDACTED].co.uk, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://10.244.1.4:443/favicon.ico", host: "[REDACTED].co.uk", referrer: "https://[REDACTED].co.uk/"
10.244.1.1 - [10.244.1.1] - - [25/Apr/2019:13:39:20 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 502 559 "https://[REDACTED].co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36" 26 0.000 [default-sub360-auth-service-443] 10.244.1.254:443, 10.244.1.3:443, 10.244.1.4:443 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.000, 0.004 502, 502, 502 63b6ed4414bf32694de3d136f7f277aa
```

Can anyone point me to what I need to look at or do to get this working now?

Comment: Why are you using a LoadBalancer type service? Have you tried ClusterIP?

Comment: I wondered about that, but does it matter? Surely the ingress controller handles routing to the service and the service handles routing to the pods?

Comment: The Load Balancer type service does not matter. It just a security problem. Maybe you can try to change the servicePort into 80. And a question, do you put the DNS name into the certificate as the document said?

Comment: I changed the servicePort to 80, then I get a different error: 
`2019/04/26 07:41:06 [error] 1706#1706: *1557212 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.244.1.1, server: [DOMAIN].co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.244.1.5:80/", host: "[DOMAIN].co.uk"` According to what I've read, this comes from trying to connect to something that isn't using SSL/TLS. Which makes sense here because port 80 on the upstream isn't using HTTPS.

Comment: Do you add the host "[DOMAIN].co.uk" in the certificate when you convert from PFX?

Comment: I did. Have actually just managed to get this working thanks to your comments. I did need to use servicePort 80 for the routing, but also I needed to remove the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"` I think that was trying to create another (invalid) SSL connection from the ingress to the service. If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Add the answer. If there is something need to improve please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue, the ingress uses the HTTPS protocol with the port 443, so you do not need to expose the port 443 for your container. Just expose the port that which your application listens to.

For you, it means you just expose the port 80 for your container and the service. You also need to remove the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"` and change the servicePort value into 80.

Note: Add the DNS name into the certificate is also important.

Comment: Perfect, that has fixed it. Thanks!